# Refactoring rails controller before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking at refactoring some code. I was wondering if there was a better way to use a before filter is it is using show, delete, edit and update.

The current bit is as follows

```
before_filter :diagnostic, only: [:show, :delete, :edit, :update]
```

Comment: This looks fine. BTW I guess you have `destroy` not `delete` action.

Comment: yes that is correct!

Comment: you can also use `except` instead of `only` if it makes it a bit cleaner, e.g. `before_filter :diagnostic, :except => [:index]`

Comment: or  `skip_before_filter :diagnostic, :only  => [:index] ` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way is to use.

```
before_filter :diagnostic, :except => [:index]
```

it is less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding that you can use

```
before_filter
```

Or

```
before_action
```

They are completely the same and it took a while for me to realise this ;)

Ref:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#action-pack-notable-changes